# How can I fix Dolphin's slow start up?

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, kde, dolphin

I've been a user of Kubuntu for 2 years now and I've upgraded the system when a new version came out. So far I was fine, but now with the Kubuntu 14.04 LTS upgrade and the KDE 4.13 also updated I found a very annoying problem:
The file manager Dolphin takes an eternity to be functional. When you open it, it comes out quickly but then it doesn't respond for as long as a minute. When finally works it's all fine, but if I close it and reopen it, it happens again.
I tried launching Dolphin from the terminal, and this is what it came out.

```
santiago@santiago-PC:~$ dolphin
Object::connect: No such signal org::freedesktop::UPower::DeviceAdded(QDBusObjectPath)
Object::connect: No such signal org::freedesktop::UPower::DeviceRemoved(QDBusObjectPath)
Bus::open: Can not get ibus-daemon's address. 
IBusInputContext::createInputContext: no connection to ibus-daemon 
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
dolphin(2841)/kdecore (K*TimeZone*): KSystemTimeZones: ktimezoned initialize() D-Bus call failed:  "Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken."
```

I never had problems with the startup speed in my previous upgrades, but since 14.04 it's really slow. I also noticed that it's only Dolphin, since Gwenview and other KDE-related programs run just fine.
I hope I made myself clear (sorry for the language, I'm from Argentina), and really hope anybody can help me. If you might need any other information please tell me and I'll provide it as quick as I can.
Thanks in advance, have a nice day.

Comment: First of all, try disabling all previews in control-configure dolphin-general.

Comment: "I changed my file manager to 'Konquerer' and 'imageviewer' (the best, light and fastest image viewer programme) which made my machine once again brisk and crisp... You can try this tip if require"

Comment: Hi there BarafuAlbino I did that and my problem was magically solved. Before that I also deleted(renamed) the .pulse folder in my home directory, because I've seen in some forums that it helped. I don't really know which one did the trick, but I stil have to thank you.
Im going to restart and check, and if it works fine I'll come to check this as Solved(Answered)
Thanks for your answer and also thanks to @drpjkurian for the information on the alternative programs, in case this doesn't work and can't get it right.

Comment: @BarafuAlbino after a restart Dolphin became really slow again, but I found something interesting but I can't figure the reason: if I change the home address in Dolphin to any other folder than my home it opens very quickly, and if I mark the "show hidden files" option (with my default home folder) it does as well. I'm not sure if this means anything so I'm still looking for help here. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of the

```
no connection to ibus-daemon
```

error following the suggestions on this thread [Is removing ibus enough?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/487083/is-removing-ibus-enough). Maybe it solves your problem.

Comment: It solved the problem. So far, so good!
Thanks mate, because it was really annoying to be on hold of my documents while it loaded.
This was a good solution, though I didn't remove the ibus, just did what said there and worked.
Thanks again friend, and have a really good day.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my file manager to 'Konquerer' and 'imageviewer' (the best, light and fastest image viewer programme) which made my machine once again brisk and crisp... You can try this tip if required.
It was posted on **[this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2219273)** thread.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged here. PLease edit this answer and include the major sections here and provide the link for reference.