# Is removing ibus enough?

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, ibus

I am using Kubuntu 14.04.

I had to completely remove ibus because not only it bugged chromium, but also I do not need it at all.

Unfortunately, I have the feeling it is not completely disabled because I have warning messages in some application logs:

```
x@aspire6930g:~$ konsole
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
x@aspire6930g:~$ Bus::open: Connect ibus failed!
IBusInputContext::createInputContext: no connection to ibus-daemon
```

As the ibus package no longer exists on my system, there is no ibus-daemon.

My question is : what additional step should I perform to tell the system that I do not use ibus ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Run `qtconfig-qt4` → Interface tab
2. Set Default Input Method to `xim`

If for some reasons didn't work, try using `im-config`:

1. Check for available & default input systems:

   ```
   $ im-config -l
   ibus xim

   $ im-config -m
   default
   ibus
   ibus
   ```
2. Set other one, `xim` is the standard for X server

   ```
   im-config -n xim
   ```

Comment: Perfect ! It works fine. I had to install qt4-qtconfig which was not installed.

Comment: By the way, the Google Chromium ibus bug looks fixed now. I enabled ibus ok and it works fine.