# Dead keys on Firefox Kubuntu 15.04

Tags: firefox, kubuntu, 15.04, ibus, dead-keys

I use the GR-el version of the latest Firefox on Kubuntu 15.04. After the latest (2015-May-1) update, I can't have dead keys produce accents for (Greek GR-el / UTF-8).
I can bypass this problem by running Firefox from the console with `sudo`.
Would there be a way to fix the problem in a simpler and permanent way?
Thank you in advance.

NB01. There is **no dead-keys problem** with any other app.
NB02. This **doesn't occur in Opera**; dead-keys for Greek are OK.
NB03. This **does happen in Mindori** (for UTF-8).

I did `sudo apt-purge firefox`, reboot, re-installation but the problem remains.
Can someone suggest antoher workaround

Is this due to some bug referring to a Ubuntu 15.04 system parameter?

PS. I re-installed Kubuntu 15.04; then I installed software and fonts I need checking firefox at each step. The problem re-appeared when I ran ttf-mscorefonts-installer. Un-installation didn't work. So, I un-installed ibus as you guys suggested, and now I have back my dead-keys.

Comment: Not working for me as well. Can make it work by calling `unset XMODIFIER` (which is `@im=ibus`). This might be a regression of https://code.google.com/p/ibus/issues/detail?id=526 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/335732 .

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it work by permanently disabling IBus with the following command (based on [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/487128/288716)):

```
im-config -n xim
```

Not sure whether IBus should be the default input method or not in new  Kubuntu/KDE. So I don't know if this is more workaround or an actual fix (and IBus should not be used at all). Would be nice if someone with more in-depth knowledge can comment on that.

---

You can get rid of *ibus* package completely by `sudo apt-get remove ibus` (see comments).

Comment: My upgrade path was from **14.04 LTS** and I ended with *ibus* installed (it was probably there from the beginning). My colleague has fresh **14.10** and he don't have *ibus* installed (checked by `im-config -l`). So by default *ibus* should probably not be present in the system at all.

Comment: Just removed `ibus` completely and everything seems fine. So feel free to get rid of it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code `im-config -l`, if it shows problems setting `LC_ALL`, put this in your `/etc/invironment` file:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

according with your locale.

Reboot and LibreOffice should now process dead keys.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems on 14.04 (and now on a freshly installed 15.04), mainly with LibreOffice and Netbeans. A solution was to unset the XMODIFIERS variable:

```
unset XMODIFIERS && commandYouWant
```

So I made some aliases for those commands. But honestly, I have no clue why this worked (apart from the fact that the problem had something to do with ibus), and what was the exact nature of the problem (more over, the problem was sometimes present, sometimes not, and sometimes suddenly the dead keys stopped working (mostly after switching windows)).