# Combining keys (e.g., " + e = ë) not working in KDE applications (dead keys)

Tags: special-characters, konsole, dead-keys, kde5

I have been using 'combining keys' such as `+ e = ë`, `~ + a = ã`, `^ + <space> = ^` for the longest time in my Kubuntu setup. I do not remember if the system came like that out of the box or if I configured it somehow.

After upgrading to Kubuntu 15.04 this functionality does not seem to work in KDE applications anymore, but it's still working fine in Firefox, Thunderbird, Atom, etc.

```
Firefox, Thunderbird, Atom: all the ones I tested work (~,`,',",^)
Konsole, Kate: none work
Rekonq: some work (~,`,^), other do not (", ')
```

I have looked through all the settings but couldn't find the relevant one.

Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this? Especially the " and ~ keys are fairly important when using the command prompt.

I have filed a bug report for the same on https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=347137, but as it might be a user error rather than a bug I'm asking it here as well.

Cheers,
Chris.

Comment: `^ + = ^` should read `^ + <space> = ^`

Comment: What do you mean with `^ + <space> = ^`?

Comment: @A.B. Normally, for example `^ + e` gives you `ê`. If you want `^` alone, you need `^ + <space>`. Regarding the question, my KDE were long ago (somewhere in the early 4.x range), but  the key word that might help you is "dead keys". Chances are that there's a setting to that effect in KDE's keyboard settings.

Comment: I still haven't been able to correct the issue. The bug report (https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=347137) hasn't been picked up yet.

Comment: I ended up reinstalling my system which solved the issue.

Comment: Anyone have a fix for this? I do not want to reinstall, konsole is bugging for me most of the time in Unity... the worst part is I cannot type ~ in konsole... surprisingly it does work sometimes though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to specify the layout under system settings > input devices > keyboard > layouts > configure layouts. Choose one with variant containing 'with dead keys'.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem where the keys were working in GTK based applications such as Firefox, but not in the Qt based applications of KDE. Some recommendations I found online were suggesting to configure or remove IBus or XIM but doing so did not help me.

Whilst checking the output of `locale` (displays current locale settings) I found the system was using `nds_DE.UTF-8` (Low Saxon). After changing this to `de_DE.UTF-8` (ordinary German) the keyboard works as expected.

The locale can be switched in KDE's System Settings in Regional Settings → Formats. After doing so `locale` outputs:

`LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES=POSIX
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=`

This gives me the system messages and UI in English whilst the formatting is German.

In order to type the characters of several European languages, using a composite key seems comfortable to me. I've set this up in KDE's System Settings in Input Devices → Keyboard → Advanced. Here you want to check “Configure keyboard options” and select “Caps Lock” in “Position of Compose key” below to give this annoying key a sensible job.

Now, you enter the characters like so:

`^` +  → ^

`~` → ~

`"` → "

`^` + `a` → â

`Caps Lock` + `e` + `"` → ë

`Caps Lock` + `a` + `a` → å

`Caps Lock` + `n` + `~` → ñ

https://cyberborean.wordpress.com/2008/01/06/compose-key-magic/ lists more of those sequences and gives some background information. Using this composite key and typing the sequences is a matter of taste but works nicely for me for languages with the occasional special character such as German, Italian, Portuguese, Swedish, … and does not require switching keyboard layouts constantly.

Answer (score 0):

Use your compose key for that:

- `ë` press <kbd>Compose</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd> and release, press <kbd>e</kbd>
- `ã` press <kbd>Compose</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> and release, press <kbd>a</kbd>
- `ê` press <kbd>Compose</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> and release, press <kbd>e</kbd>

My compose key is the [menu key](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Kontextmen%C3%BC.jpg):

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options
['terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp', 'compose:menu']
```

Comment: Hi A.B., thank you for your response. The gsettings command yields "@as []" which probably means no compose key? Before the update (and still in non-KDE applications) the old combination without compose key worked just fine. I'll Google for 'dead keys' as suggested in your other response to see what comes up.

Comment: Where is a result? :)

Comment: Sorry, had pressed enter too early. Have edited the response. Dead keys brings me to http://askubuntu.com/questions/616755/dead-keys-on-firefox-kubuntu-15-04. Will try if that solution works for me as well.